# How do I acquire the data in a json response from a POST request in Next/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using Next.js api route to handle a POST request then send a response back to the frontend. I have used Rapid API client extension to confirm there is a response being sent to the frontend. I just dont know how to handle it in the frontend.

Here is the code on the api route:

```js
import clientPromise from "../../../config/mongodb";

export default async function userDetailsHandler(req, res) {
  const body = req.body;

  if (req.method == "POST") {
    const client = await clientPromise;
    const db = client.db("mood-board");
    let emailQuery = await db
      .collection("users")
      .find({ email: body.email })
      .limit(1)
      .toArray();
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emailQuery));
    res.status(200).json(parsedData)
    console.log(parsedData)
  } else if(req.method = "GET") {
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following example, you use the fetch api to post the data which returns a promise. You can use then() which takes a callback function that you can use to operate on the data once that promise is returned.

Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // POST request using fetch inside useEffect React hook
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ title: 'React Hooks POST Request Example' })
    };
    fetch('https://reqres.in/api/posts', requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setPostId(data.id));

// empty dependency array means this effect will only run once (like componentDidMount in classes)
}, []);
```